# index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to avoid using any in the following case

```js
type Cache = Partial<Record<Language, string>>;

const cache: Cache = {};

export const init = (directory: string): Promise<void[]> =>
  fsPromise.readdir(directory).then(files =>
    Promise.all(
      files
        .filter(files => files.endsWith('.json'))
        .map(async file => {
          cache[file.slice(0, -5) as Language] = await import(`${directory}/${file}`);
        })
    )
  );

export const translate = (lang: Language): ((query: string) => string) => (key: string) =>
  key.split('.').reduce((acc, val) => acc[val], cache[lang]);
```

I tried `val as keyof acc` but that wouldn't work, which type should the val be?

Comment: It would be `keyof ((typeof cache)[Language])`, whatever that is, because `cache[lang]` is the `seed`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, inside the reduce param it gives me `'Cache' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` and casting gives me `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

Comment: It is case sensitive. If you've posted your actual code, then `cache` available is in scope

Comment: I have edited the post to include the full code, lower case only gives me some extended error

Comment: I don't think you code makes sense. `acc` has type `string` but strings can only be indexed by `number` (per TypeScript): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgYwBbQLxQEoQQewE4AmAPADJwB2A5gK5yUQA0UAzsHgJZUB8A3AFChIUMlVr0o6AEQRykqAB8okgF5JJ-PrnKsoCRCglQi8ZBC4BvAL4aIADzD5gunNqdsKzADZxgaKAApvKgAuYQoaOggASlD-fwBHagg8EFDWDiooiS4WNk5KLNQc-z4oKABrCFTcjMo+QpzKkAA6ZjBPdmB-SWbJKOa8CAJqBAg4xAQmADc4TwaoCYBtGc8AXSY9U0WgylWo-iA

Answer (score 2):

Type definition of reduce you're using:

**reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U;**

Your case:
**U = string**, *since every key in Cache has value of type string.*
**T = string**, *since reduce is on Split(`Array<string>`).*

**So going through your code val will always be string. Type of val is strictly dependent on the Array<`T`> on which reduce is run i.e. T here and string if using your example.**

For val's type to be *keyof Cache* the Reduce operation has to run on an Array<`keyof Cache`>.

Something like:

```
type Cache = Partial<Record<'key1' | 'key2', string>>
arr: Array<keyof Cache> = ['key1', 'key2']
arr.reduce((acc: SomeCustomType | Cache, val: keyof Cache) => some return logic here, Impl of SomeCustomType| Cache)
```